# How to create shadow table in Informix

Tags: database, stored-procedures, informix

I was working on an audit trail module that require me to create a huge list of shadow table from original table. I was thinking to write a stored procedure that could generate a shadow table from another table. This table could be any table, it could be table_A that consist of 3 fields of any data type, or table_B that consist of 10 fields of any data type, and that could base on the parameter pass into the store procedure.

I know I can retrieve a list of fields available to the particular table_A from syscolumns and systables like this:

```
select * from syscolumns where tabid = (select tabid from systables where tabname='table_A')
```

There will be a list of fields return from this statement, lets say field_A, then I will rename this field_A to create 2 new fields which is pre_field_A and post_field_A, and then use these 2 new fields to create a shadow table of shadow_table_A. Apply this concept to the rest of the fields. Need not worry about the data type of a field because this information already there in syscolumns, and I can just dup it over to shadow table.

I am currently stuck at how could I store the list of values return from the statement above, because usually any table will consist of more than one field. Can it be done using array? or any alternate solution to create shadow table for audit trail purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query will work, but it might be more idiomatic to use a join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "informix".systables AS t
  JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c ON t.tabid = c.tabid
 WHERE t.tabname = 'table_a';
```

Also, be aware that the system catalog will only contain `table_A` in mixed case if you created the table while you had DELIMIDENT set in the environment and you created the table with the name enclosed in double quotes.  Normally, the table name will be in all lower-case letters in the system catalog; similarly for column names.

However, that's all tangential to your question.  Dealing with user-defined types in all their glory is painful.  However, if you're dealing with normal databases, you can certainly work like that, though it might be easier to use DB-Schema (`dbschema`) to generate the schema for a table, and then trap that.  You could actually do that through a stored procedure using the SYSTEM statement, but I'd probably do it from outside a stored procedure.  It does depend on what else you need to do.  The pre-image and post-image for each field could be modestly costly.

If you have IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.70, you can create your CREATE {audit} TABLE statement dynamically, and then execute the statement.  So, you'd build up your query using a FOREACH loop in the stored procedure to add each column in turn, and then execute the statement to create the audit table.  You'll have to decode the type, too.  You could/should use a procedure for that, too.  I'm assuming that `tabname` is a variable passed to the stored procedure, and `c_colno`, `c_colname`, and `c_typename` are local variables (as is `cts`, short for 'create table statement', and `pad`):

```
LET cts = 'CREATE TABLE ' || tabname || '(';
LET pad = '';
FOREACH SELECT c.colno, c.colname, type_name(c.coltype, c.collength)
          INTO c_colno, c_colname, c_typename
          FROM "informix".systables AS t
          JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c
            ON t.tabid = c.tabid
         WHERE t.tabname = tabname
         ORDER BY c.colno
    LET cts = cts || pad || 'pre_'  || c_colname || ' ' || c_coltype;
    LET cts = cts || ',' || 'post_' || c_colname || ' ' || c_coltype;
    LET pad = ',';
END FOREACH;
LET cts = cts || ');';
```

You may want to deal with NOT NULL and primary key constraints and all sorts of other things, but this gives you the basics to be going on with.

Comment: May I know how can I execute the cts statement in stored procedure?

Comment: If you execute this with `Informix 11.50` the `cts` variable is rewrite every column (in each `foreach`), is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: I wasn't aware (or had forgotten) that 11.50 supported dynamic SQL in stored procedures.  Putting that aside, the notation assumes `cts` is a VARCHAR or (more likely) LVARCHAR type.  If it is CHAR, I think you run into truncation problems with `cts = cts || …` as the blanks at the end aren't removed before more data is concatenated to the end of `cts`.  You might need to use `cts = TRIM(cts) || …`.  However, the intent is definitively that you should end up with a single-line CREATE TABLE statement in `cts`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I Change for `LVARCHAR`, and works fine, I add the `type_name` procedure as another answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10117108/15168), there is the `type_name` procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE type_name(coltype INTEGER, colsize INTEGER)
            RETURNING VARCHAR(128);
            DEFINE toRet                    VARCHAR(128);

            DEFINE size_5                   VARCHAR(5);
            DEFINE decimal_p, decimal_s     INTEGER;
            DEFINE decimal_t                VARCHAR(16);
            DEFINE varchar_m, varchar_n     INTEGER;
            DEFINE varchar_t                VARCHAR(16);

            LET size_5 = '(' || TRIM(CAST(colsize AS CHAR(5))) || ')'; 
            -- Precision
            LET decimal_p = TRUNC(colsize/256);
            -- Scale
            LET decimal_s = colsize - 256 * decimal_p;
            -- Decimal total
            LET decimal_t = '(' || TRIM(CAST(decimal_p as VARCHAR(8))) || ',' || TRIM(CAST(decimal_s as VARCHAR(8))) || ')';

            -- VARCHAR(M,N)
            LET varchar_n = decimal_p;
            LET varchar_m = decimal_s;
            LET varchar_t = '(' || TRIM(CAST(varchar_m as VARCHAR(8))) || ',' || TRIM(CAST(varchar_n as VARCHAR(8))) || ')';

            SELECT
                CASE coltype
                    WHEN 0   THEN 'char' || size_5 
                    WHEN 1   THEN 'smallint'
                    WHEN 2   THEN 'integer'
                    WHEN 3   THEN 'float'
                    WHEN 4   THEN 'smallfloat'
                    WHEN 5   THEN 'decimal' || decimal_t
                    WHEN 6   THEN 'serial'
                    WHEN 7   THEN 'date'
                    WHEN 8   THEN 'money' || decimal_t
                    WHEN 9   THEN 'null'
                    WHEN 10  THEN 'DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(3)'
                    WHEN 11  THEN 'byte'
                    WHEN 12  THEN 'TEXT'
                    WHEN 13  THEN 'VARCHAR' || varchar_t
                    WHEN 14  THEN 'INTERVAL'
                    WHEN 15  THEN 'NCHAR' || size_5
                    WHEN 16  THEN 'NVARCHAR' || varchar_t
                    WHEN 17  THEN 'INT8'
                    WHEN 18  THEN 'SERIAL8'
                    WHEN 19  THEN 'SET'
                    WHEN 20  THEN 'MULTISET'
                    WHEN 21  THEN 'LIST'
                    WHEN 22  THEN 'ROW'
                    WHEN 23  THEN 'COLLECTION'
                    WHEN 24  THEN 'ROWDEF'
                    WHEN 40  THEN 'LVARCHAR'  || size_5 
                    WHEN 256 THEN 'CHAR' || size_5 || ' NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 257 THEN 'SMALLINT NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 258 THEN 'INTEGER NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 259 THEN 'FLOAT NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 260 THEN 'SMALLFLOAT NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 261 THEN 'DECIMAL' || decimal_t || ' NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 262 THEN 'SERIAL NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 263 THEN 'DATE NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 264 THEN 'MONEY' || decimal_t || ' NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 265 THEN 'null NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 266 THEN 'DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(3) NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 267 THEN 'BYTE NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 268 THEN 'TEXT NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 269 THEN 'VARCHAR' || varchar_t || ' NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 270 THEN 'INTERVAL NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 271 THEN 'nchar(' || size_5 || ') NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 272 THEN 'nvarchar' || varchar_t || ' NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 273 THEN 'int8 NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 274 THEN 'serial8 NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 275 THEN 'set NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 276 THEN 'multiset NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 277 THEN 'list NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 278 THEN 'row NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 279 THEN 'collection NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 280 THEN 'rowdef NOT NULL'
                    WHEN 296 THEN 'LVARCHAR'  || varchar_t || ' NOT NULL'
                    ELSE 'ERROR'
                END datatype
            INTO toRet
            FROM systables
            WHERE tabid = 1;
            IF toRet = 'ERROR' THEN
               RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, 'Unknow datatype ' || coltype;
            END IF

            RETURN toRet;
    END PROCEDURE;
```

Credit to [this](http://www.dbforums.com/informix/1619539-translate-column-data-type.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Is the `CASE 2` correct?  Doesn't it always return 'integer'?  It should, I think, be `CASE coltype`.  Similarly in the `CAST(2...` in the `ELSE` clause at the end.  The code doesn't decode DATETIME or INTERVAL; it also doesn't recognize [N]VARCHAR(255,3) notation (it will report that as size 1023, I believe).

Comment: Fixed the `CASE 2` (it was for debug purposes). In the case of the `VARCHAR(M,N)`, the length is `1023`, is correct the formula: `M=colsize - 256 * N` and `N=TRUNC(colsize/256)`?, Thanks for the help, I am a newbiew with informix.

Comment: Yes; the low-order 8 bits encode the overall length of a [N]VARCHAR column, and the high-order 8 bits (usually zero) encode the minimum length.